# How to make duplicate records

Tags: mongodb

I want to duplicate my all records in my collection of mongodb.

eg:
my collection have 1500 records so i need to change it into 3000.
means double

I need any query which can do this in one command

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything using `find` then use `foreach` loop to insert it again.

```
db.col.find({},{_id:0}).forEach((doc)=>{db.col.save(doc)});
```

Make sure to remove `_id` because every duplicate is going to have its own unique `_id`

Comment: i am using robomongo 3T
can i apply this query on it

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can, I personally never worked with it but if it allows you to write queries then yes!